# Issue installing kernel-devel on CentOS

Tags: centos, virtualbox

So I am trying to install Guest Additions in my VirtualBox Vm which is running CentOS.

I am getting this error though:

```
The headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the following
module compilation fails then this could be the reason.
The missing package can be probably installed with
yum install kernel-devel-2.6.32-279.5.2.el6.x86_64
```

When I try to run the yum install command mentioned in the error, I get:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ox.ac.uk
 * epel: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * extras: centos.serverspace.co.uk
 * updates: centos.serverspace.co.uk
Setting up Install Process
No package kernel-devel-2.6.32-279.5.2.el6.x86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: if you just try to do a `yum install kernel-devel` ?

Answer (score 3):

It's not unlikely that centos has published a kernel update. Run `yum install kernel-devel` and `yum update kernel`. Then reboot into the newer kernel.

Answer (score 0):

As a privileged user try:

```
# yum update
# yum install kernel-devel
# yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Reboot the system, mount the Guest Additions CD and autorun.

I find it helpful to reboot again after the Guest additions has been installed.

You may find [my blog post](http://wp.me/p36f2N-5hd) about the detailed process that I use to setup Vagrant boxes helpful.  It outlines the Guest Additions issues as part of the Vagrant setup process including screen shots.

Comment: That is a dead link.

Comment: @EEAA - I am updating the article, it will be live shortly as soon as I verify the information is updated and accurate.